# Create a static column item

Tags: python, web-scraping, screen-scraping, scrapy

I have a simple spider that crawls local obituaries. The code works perfectly until I try to add two static columns. All I want to do is add the date I pulled the information (pull item) and the state in which it was pulled (state item). It's a self loading page so when I add the pull date, I only get the first 10 results (or only the first page). If I add just the state, I only get two results. When I remove both, I get all 40+ results.

I did # lines that aren't working properly:

Item.py file:

```
import scrapy


class AlItem(scrapy.Item):
    name = scrapy.Field()
    link = scrapy.Field()
    obit = scrapy.Field()
    news = scrapy.Field()
    #pull = scrapy.Field()
    #state = scrapy.Field()
```

spider file:

```
import scrapy
import time
from al.items import AlItem

class AlabamaSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'alabama'
    allowed_domains = ['legacy.com']
    start_urls = ['http://www.legacy.com/obituaries/annistonstar/browse?type=paid&page=20']

    def parse(self, response):
    name = response.xpath('//a[@class="NonMobile"]/p[@class="obitName"]/text()').extract()
    link = response.xpath('//div[@class="RightColumn"]//a[@class="ObituaryButton"]/@href').extract()
    obit = response.xpath('//div[@class="NameAndLocation"]/p[@class="obitText"]/text()').extract()
    news = response.xpath('//div[@class="PublishedLine publishedLine"]/span/text()').extract()
    #pull = time.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
    #state = "AL"

    for item in zip(name, link, obit, news): #removed 'pull, state'

        new_item = AlItem()

        new_item['name'] = item[0]
        new_item['link'] = item[1]
        new_item['obit'] = item[2]
        new_item['news'] = item[3]
        #new_item['pull'] = pull
        #new_item["state"] = state

        yield new_item
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I explain why:

1. if you paste in here `for item in zip(name, link, obit, news):` pull & state, then you will get the number of iterations equal **2** because `state = "AL"` - string variable. ZIP function get from `state` two chars and set iteration = 2 for all arguments in loop. zip gets the smallest numb from arguments for iteration. as with the date 01/01/2001 - 10 chars. (will iterations equal **10**)

**WILL WORKING:**

```
`class AlItem(scrapy.Item):
  name = scrapy.Field()
  link = scrapy.Field()
  obit = scrapy.Field()
  news = scrapy.Field()
  pull = scrapy.Field()
  state = scrapy.Field()`
```

`class AlabamaSpider(scrapy.Spider):
      name = 'alabama'
      allowed_domains = ['legacy.com']
      start_urls = ['http://www.legacy.com/obituaries/annistonstar/browsetype=paid&page=20']`

```
    def parse(self, response):
        name = response.xpath('//a[@class="NonMobile"]/p[@class="obitName"]/text()').extract()
        link = response.xpath('//div[@class="RightColumn"]//a[@class="ObituaryButton"]/@href').extract()
        obit = response.xpath('//div[@class="NameAndLocation"]/p[@class="obitText"]/text()').extract()
        news = response.xpath('//div[@class="PublishedLine publishedLine"]/span/text()').extract()
        pull = time.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
        state = "AL"

        for item in zip(name, link, obit, news): #removed 'pull, state'

            new_item = AlItem()

            new_item['name'] = item[0]
            new_item['link'] = item[1]
            new_item['obit'] = item[2]
            new_item['news'] = item[3]
            new_item['pull'] = pull
            new_item["state"] = state

            yield new_item
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I looked online for the solution and found the function: zip_longest. I changed zip to zip_longest. from itertools import zip_longest.

Comment: Yep, this option will also work. Good luck in programming !!)